# Trying to dual boot windows 11 with Pop1_Os, what is correct or best disk partition for this?

Tags: partitioning

Taking a course on Linux and learning how to code , but I have many issues with playing league of legends in my free time. So I decided to dual boot.
I have 2 nvme m.2 sticks (each 500gb) and a 240 ssd . So 1240 total . Any Ideas how to partition properly? I only use Linux for my course and coding I don’t think ill need that much of disk space for it.

I’ve tried to install them and do it by myself but I always screw up the windows files somehow.